# Java - How do I extract Google News Titles and Links using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am very new to using jsoup and html. I was wondering how to extract the titles and links (if possible) from the stories on the front page of google news. Here is my code:

```
    org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup.connect("https://news.google.com/").get();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Elements titles = doc.select("titletext");

                System.out.println("Titles: " + titles.text());


                //non existent
                for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element e: titles) {
                    System.out.println("Title: " + e.text());
                    System.out.println("Link: " + e.attr("href"));
                }
```

For some reason I think my program is unable to find `titletext`, since this is the output when the code runs: `Titles:`

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: try doc.select("span.titletext");

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the much easier to parse [RSS feed](https://news.google.com/news?output=rss)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get all nodes/elements which start with h2 html tag

```
Elements elem = html.select("h2");
```

Now you have element it has some child element(s) (id, href, originalhref and so on). Here you need retrieve these data which you need

```
 for(Element e: elem){
         System.out.println(e.select("[class=titletext]").text());
         System.out.println(e.select("a").attr("href"));
     }
```